# Brownian Motion hitting times in one dimension

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Brownian Motion starting from $0$. Define for $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $$T_a = \inf\{t\geq0:X_t=a\}.$$
For $a,b>0$, show that $\mathbb{P}(T_{-a}<T_b)=\frac{b}{a+b}$. I really don't have any idea how to show this formally (intuitively it makes sense), so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It really depends what you already know as to how this is most easily shown. One way you can go is via the backward Kolmogorov equation; from here you can show that with $u(x)=P_x(T_{-a}<T_b)$ you have $u''=0,u(-a)=1,u(b)=0$. But this is a somewhat long way around.

Comment: What's the intuitive reason it makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to let $T=T_{-a}\wedge T_b$ consider the stopped process $X^T$. $X^T$ is uniformly integrable as it is bounded between $-a$ and $b$, and so we can use the optional stopping theorem for non-bounded stopping times: $$\mathbb{E}(X_T^T)=\mathbb{E}(X_0^T)=0.$$

Then $$\mathbb{E}(X_T^T)=-\mathbb{P}(T_{-a}<T_b)a+\mathbb{P}(T_{-a}>T_b)b$$ and solving using that $\mathbb{P}(T_{-a}>T_b) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(T_{-a}<T_b)$ gives the result.

Comment: This is correct; to nitpick, you still should show that $P(T < \infty) = 1$ (i.e. $T$ is almost surely finite). Two proofs: (i) follows from $\limsup B_t = + \infty$ and $\liminf B_t = - \infty$, or by (ii) showing $E(T) < \infty$, which I do in my answer to your related question.